# Dialog UI freezed/unresponsive until all the elements are finished loading into my Qlistwidget. Any way to solve this?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qlistwidget, qdialog

In my dialog i have qlistwidget and a "refresh-list" button, when i click refresh-list `button` this function

```
Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0);
```

should run and it populates my qlistwidget with around 10000 items, but until this function prepares and adds 10000 items in my qlistwidget ,the UI remains frozen ,i am not able to see list-items being added sequentially but after a period of 2 mins of being unresponsive, it suddenly becomes perfectly responsive.

How to tackle this ?? my desired effect is that,when this function is running , i should be able to see the elements adding up one-by-one/realtime in the QListwidget while the UI remains resonsive.

Note (My try):- to acheive my desired effect, i have tried running that `Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0);` function in a separate thread named "thread3" , and when i click `refresh` button, i was able to see the list-items being added in-front of me and the UI remained resposive, but i had a problem, when i clicked "Ok" ENTIRE UI CRASHES, i get errors in either `qlist.h` or `abort.cpp` The way i did it was like this---

```
void Dialog::on_refreshbutton_clicked()
{
    std::thread thread3(&KeyComd::Print_step,this);
    thread3.detach(); 
}
void KeyComd::Print_step()
{
    Print_Descendants_key(exc.pUIAutomation, nullptr, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use qlistview instead of qlistwidget. You can apply a delegate to either the widget or the view to control how data is displayed. You can use a custom delegate to do the background colour, or you can use the model Qt::BackgroundRole to suggest a colour to the default delegate. Which option you choose is driven by numerous factors including convenience and the form the source data takes.

To create your own custom model you derive from QAbstractTableModel, QAbstractListModel or QAbstractItemModel depending on the form of your data. Create your model in different QThread, then the signals of this model will be connected to view using Qt::QueuedConnection, and your ui will not be blocked.

If so...and your model is read-only through the view widget then yes, you have to lock. I'd argue that doing so undermines the elegance of the "decoupling" provided by the model/view separation. But it could be made to work.

However...if your model is read-write through the view it's not possible to do correctly at all because of the queued nature of the notification slots. Here's an archive of a mailing list conversation I had on the qt-interest mailing list on the topic:

http://blog.hostilefork.com/qt-model-view-different-threads/

```
"The short version is that I don't think it's feasible for a Model to
be modified on a non-GUI thread...regardless of whether the model's
data has been protected with read/write locks. If what I'm gathering
is correct, then Qt should probably have an assert that a model and
its view have the same thread affinity (it doesn't seem to do that now)"
```

Answer (score 0):

sonulohani's suggestion of using a `QListView` and subclassing `QAbstractListModel` is a good one, as it allows you to display a large N-item list directly from your raw data, without having to create N separate `QListItem` objects.  If you think your lists are going to get extremely large (e.g. hundreds of thousands of items, millions of items, etc), then that is the way to go.

My answer, OTOH, is just to provide a somewhat easier-to-implement alternative approach that might be "good enough" for your purposes.

If you know your `Print_Descendants_key()` function is likely to take a long time to execute, one way to run it inside the the GUI thread(*) without freezing up the GUI is to have it run for just a few milliseconds each time it is called, and then reschedule itself to run again.

That is, instead of this:

```
void MyClass :: Print_Descendants_key()
{
   // loop that takes a long time to complete, freezing up the GUI, yuck!
   for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
   {
      myListWidget->addItem(new QListItem(...));
   }
}
```

.... you could do something like this:

```
#include <QTimer>

MyClass :: MyClass()
   : _curIndex(0)
   , _numIndices(10000)
{
   QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(AddMoreItems()));  // start us off...
}

// Declared as a private slot in the .h file
void MyClass :: AddMoreItems()
{
   int numItemsToAdd = (_numIndices - _curIndex);
   if (numItemsToAdd > 100) numItemsToAdd = 100;

   // Add just a few items, so it won't take too long
   for (int i=_curIndex; i<_curIndex+numItemsToAdd; i++)
   {
      myListWidget->addItem(new QListItem(...));
   }
   _curIndex += numItemsToAdd;

   if (_curIndex < _numIndices) 
   {
      // Still more to do?  Then schedule us to be called again ASAP.
      QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(AddMoreItems()));
   }
}
```

This way any other GUI events (window-resizes, or whatever) will still get handled in a reasonably timely manner, since `AddMoreItems()` will never work for more than a few milliseconds before it returns and allows the GUI event-loop to do whatever else it might need to do.  You can modify the maximum value of `numValuesToAdd` and/or the first argument to the `QTimer::singleShot()` calls to adjust the behavior, if necessary.

(*) It has to be run inside the GUI thread, because non-GUI threads are not allowed to interact with Qt GUI objects -- that is why your program crashes when you try to offload your `Print_Descendants_key()` method to a separate thread.